# how to declare UPDATE SYNTAX using CODEIGNITER?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

can you please help me to my problem

I try to insert a button in VIEW

```
<button type="button" class="btn green button-submit" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("controller/fun_name");?>'">Sign Up</button>**
```

In Model, I declare Update Syntax

```
public function updateStatus($input)
{
    $data = array(
            'status' => 'Approved'
        );

        $this->db->where('pr_id', $prid);
        $this->db->update('t_purchaserequest', $data);
}
```

And in Controller:

```
public function updateStatus()
{
    $output = null;
    $response = null;
    $output = $this->ARequestModel->updateStatus($_POST);

    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    $this->output->set_output(print(json_encode($output)));
    exit();
}
```

and it's not working, I try all the possibilities still I Failed...

I anyone, can you please help me fix my problem

thank you

Comment: Define "it's not working" - error messages, etc. - and what "all the possibilities" were.

Comment: i try to change the format and the syntax in my model and controller,

Comment: it is not working, when i click the button, i did not update the status field in my database? I search some codes and apply it to my system still it did not update the status...

Answer (score 1):

you should use $input like this in your model:

```
public function updateStatus($input)
{
$data = array(
        'status' => 'Approved'
    );

    $this->db->where('pr_id', $input['pr_id']);
    $this->db->update('t_purchaserequest', $data);
    return $this->db->get_where('t_purchaserequest', array('pr_id' =>$input['pr_id']))->result();
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public function updateStatus()
{
$output = null;
$output = $this->ARequestModel->updateStatus($_POST);

$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($output));
 exit();
}
```

Comment: Unknown column 'prid' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`t_purchaserequest`) WHERE `prid` IS NULL

this is my error, after I apply your suggestion

Comment: what is the name of column ??

Comment: try pr_id instead of prid

Comment: status is the name of my column that i have to update,

Comment: I try to change the $prid into pr_id... this are the errors

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: pr_id

Filename: models/ARequestModel.php

Line Number: 182
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: pr_id

Filename: models/ARequestModel.php

Line Number: 180

---------------------------------------------

Unknown column 'prid' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`t_purchaserequest`) WHERE `prid` IS NULL

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\mms\system\database\DB_driver.php

Comment: return $this->db->get_where('t_purchaserequest', array('pr_id' =>$input['pr_id']))->result();
}

this area... i try to reconstruct, because it does not work... 

i try this

$data = array(
        'status' => 'Approved'
    );

    $this->db->where('pr_id');
    $this->db->update('t_purchaserequest', $data);

still the status of the selected pr_id does not change...

please help me.. thank you so much

Comment: @Jhesie  *note: You have named your filename wrong should only be the first letter upper case same goes for classes* https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

first time read this question, i just ask Where do you get the $prid varriable?
that's not defined varriable.

but if $prid have the value, you can write in your model like this.

if you parse the data and id from the controller you can write like this

```
 public function updateStatus($input)
{
    $data = array(
            'status' => 'Approved'
        );

        $this->db->update($yourtable, $data['status'], $id);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

I hope it can solve your problem. correct me if i wrong.

Comment: $prid = $this->getPRID($input['id']);  this is the content of PRID.... but this part belongs to other table, that is why I did not include it here

Comment: @Jhesie is the $prid getting from the view input?

Comment: yes, the $prid is for filtering of PRcode, (Purchase Request)

Comment: if you post the value from input view. you can write this in the controller.
$this->input->post('your input'); then you parse that to your model. need an example?

Comment: yes, if you may... and if it is OK, you may use the codes given above... thank you very much

Comment: where must i give the example? in here? or I edit in my answer?

Comment: would you mind to send me the example in my email

peralta.jessicacrystin@gmail.com

thank you